# Creating an Interface of a data consist of object and array of objects

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a data set like this:-

```
data = {
   restDetails":{
           id:1
           name:"Rest1"
     },
    menus:[{
           id:1,
           name:"Dish1"
      },
      {
           id:1,
           name:"Dish2"
      }]
}
```

I am new to Angular 5.
I want to create an interface for this data set in Angular 5 project.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JSON2TS`](http://www.jsontots.com/) to create an interface based on your JSON data,

```
interface RootObject {
  restDetails: RestDetails;
  menus: RestDetails[];
}

interface RestDetails {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```